# Why does my second TypeError exception (checks for row size in matrice) not trigger the None return exception at the end. The rest do perfectly

Tags: python, exception

I have three TypeError exceptions, the first checking if the input matrice has only integers and floats. The second verifies if each row is the same size. The third checks if the divisor is an integer or float. The function should divide each element of the matrice with the divisor. The ZeroDivisionError checks if the divisor is a zero, to avoid an infinite result.

Now, each exception I placed works perfectly in detecting any errors with regards to the conditions above. Only issue is, I'd like there to be no return value/output if an exception is raised. The first and third TypeError work perfectly, the ZeroDivisionError too. They give the error message and no output. The second TypeError, however, does the opposite and executes the contents of the last try clause, which returns the matrice of all the values divided. The output therefore has both an error message, and an output, which isn't desirable. What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
#2-matrix_divided.py

def matrix_divided(matrix, div):
    """
    This function divides all elements of matrice
    by a value div
    """
    counter = 0
    verify = []
    break_out_flag = False
    for i in matrix:
        for j in i:
            try:
                if type(j) not in [int, float]:
                    raise TypeError
            except TypeError:
                print("matrix must be a matrix (list of lists) of integers/floats")
                break_out_flag = True
                break
        if break_out_flag:
            break
    try:
        for i in matrix:
            for j in i:
                counter += 1
            if counter not in verify and len(verify) > 0:
                raise TypeError
            else:
                verify.append(counter)
                counter = 0
    except TypeError:
        print("Each row of the matrix must have the same size")
    try:
        if type(div) not in [int, float]:
            raise TypeError
        if div == 0:
            raise ZeroDivisionError
    except TypeError:
        print("div must be a number")
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("division by zero")
    try:
        return [[round(j/div, 2) for j in i] for i in matrix]
    except (TypeError, ZeroDivisionError):
        return
```

These are some tests I did and as you can see it gave an output despite the exception

```
>>> z = __import__('2-matrix_divided').matrix_divided
>>> z([[2, 4], [6, 8, 10]], 2)                    
Each row of the matrix must have the same size
[[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0, 5.0]]

"""But if i trigger any of the other
exceptions, it works perfectly"""

>>> z([[2, 4], [6, "f"]], 2)
matrix must be a matrix (list of lists) of integers/floats

>>> z([[2, 4], [6, 6]], "f")
div must be a number

>>> z([[2, 4], [6, 6]], 0)
division by zero

"""Weirdly, if i trigger that same exception with
any of the other three that work, or all of them
together, they work perfectly"""

>>> z([[2, 4], [6, 8, "f"]], 2)
matrix must be a matrix (list of lists) of integers/floats
Each row of the matrix must have the same size

>>> z([[2, 4], [6, 6, "f"]], 0)
matrix must be a matrix (list of lists) of integers/floats
Each row of the matrix must have the same size
division by zero
```

Why does that one exception not work? Sorry if my code is bulky
I'm a beginner.